# Software to visualise multivariable functions $f:Z^2\rightarrow Z^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, graphing-functions, math-software, integer-lattices

I want to visualize the division algorithm as a function $f:Z^2\rightarrow Z^2$ . That is, given a unique value of (dividend, divisor) [$Z^2$ - domain], it will give a unique value of (quotient, remainder) [$Z^2$ - range] as is stated in the definition of the division algorithm.

I want to visualize this as a mapping from a plane with all integer points to another plane with all integer points (a 2-dimensional integer lattice, also called a square or grid lattice) . Can you suggest me any program for PC where I can do this and any source on how to do this?

Comment: So $Z^2$ is the lattice of integers, correct?

Comment: @JW yes. I want to plot a function from the latiice Z^2 to the lattice Z^2.

Comment: Various software (Mathematica, Maple, SageMath, Desmos, etc.) allows you to plot points (on a grid if you like). I guess the question is to show which points get mapped where, perhaps using arrows or colours? Or do you want a vector field on a lattice?

Comment: I want to visualise which points gets mapped to which points via colours.

Comment: @SohamSarkar If you pick Mathematica, ColorFunction and ColorFunctionScaling options of, say, ListPlot might be just what you need.

Comment: Just a thought, but do you have some background in programming? Using your favourite programming language might also be a relatively straightforward way to get such a plot.

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, do you have a particular reason for wanting to make such a plot?

Comment: I want to visualise the division algorithm as a $f:Z^2\rightarrow Z^2$ i.e., (dividend,divisor) to (quotient,remainder)

Comment: Although your question is more general, you might want to edit it to include the information (use of colours and reason being visualizing the division algorithm) you've supplied in the comments.

Comment: Also, if you are interested in visualising elementary number theory, take a look at Weissman's [An Illustrated Theory of Numbers](http://illustratedtheoryofnumbers.com/) and perhaps also his [introduction to Python programming](http://illustratedtheoryofnumbers.com/prog.html) for number theoretic applications.

Comment: This is not a question of programming, but of design: You have to think carefully how you want to present the information contained in a $f:\>{\mathbb Z}^2\to{\mathbb Z}^2$ graphically. The software problem then will be easy to solve.

Answer (score 2):

See WolframAlpha which is powered by Mathematica: https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/plotting-and-graphics/

You may want to probably use ListPointPlot3D function to plot points on a 3D space.
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html

You need to derive a parameter $t$ as a function of two variables (one from the domain and another from the range). Then you can form a 3D coordinate and then you can use the 3D plots in Mathematica/WolframAlpha. This is one possible visualization. The [link for ListPointPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html) has some nice examples.

If you want to map a point to another and visualize it using colors, then derive a parametric function $c: Z^2 \rightarrow Z$ that maps a point to an integer in a color space (eg: RGB colorspace) and draw an integer lattice where the lattice points are colored based on $c(x,y)$. For this you can use the [ListPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) function. The link shows an example for varying the size and color of the points plotted (See example for *[Use individual colors for each point](https://wolfram.com/xid/0wgs3aa-7abkax)*).